# Why 0 is omitted in SecFilterForceByteRange , modSecurity?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-security2

What is the meaning of `SecFilterForceByteRange 1 255`, in modSecurity ?
Some web examples provide range `0 255`, some `1 255`. Why `0` is omitted?

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modsecurity-htaccess-tricks/

Answer (score 2):

SecFilterForceByteRange has not been used since ModSecurity v1 which no one should be using anymore!

It has been replaced by [validateByteRange](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#validateByteRange) in ModSecurity v2.

But to answer your question it will stop the null byte from being allowed in those variables. For most variables the null byte shouldn't be used as this is a string terminator in most languages, so any use of it may be an indicator of an attack attempt by early terminating a string.